# LSTM VAD сеть плохо обучается

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, распознавание-речи, voice-recognition

Здравствуйте!
Решил попробовать обучить LSTM сеть с помощью caffe, до этого имел дело только с CNN.
В качестве решаемой задачи выбрал детектор речи (VAD).
Имеется небольшая размеченная выборка. Записи различной длительности.
Вектор признаков формируется следующим образом: беру окно в 25мс и вычисляю 13 MFCC + их производную, так для всей записи,
при этом шаг 20мс.
Полученные данные сохраняю в hdf5.

В сеть данные подаю следующим образом:
за одну итерацию в сеть подается один вектор MFCC, и label для него который принимает значение 0-шум или 1-речь.
Так же подаю одно значение cont_sentence, которое сбрасывается каждые 40 векторов (обнуляет внутренние регистры lstm), 
таким образом сеть все время работает с сигналом длительностью 40 кадров.
Подскажите правильный ли подход для подачи данных я выбрал?
В данный момент конфигурация сети такая:
input -> LSTM(50) -> sigmoid -> LSTM(25) -> IP(256) -> dropOut -> IP(1) -> sigmoid

К сожалению сеть плохо обучается...

**P.S.** И еще вопрос, как в дальнейшем в рабочем проекте подавать данные, интересует именно cont_sentence, нужно ли его сбрасывать каждые 40 кадров?

Comment: Добавил метку [tag:машинное-обучение]. Если ошибся — правку можно откатить [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/719739/revisions).